# Send data as struct in UDP sendto

Tags: c++, networking

How do I send the data in struct in UDP sendto in C++?

```
struct routingTable{
    int numServers;
    int numNeighbors;
    int selfId,neighborNode[5];
    int Cost[6][6];
};

routingTable selfRoutingTable;
sendto(listener_socket,<This is a char *> , strlen(my_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&nbaddr, sizeof(nbaddr)
```

Comment: Err, with a cast, and `sizeof` instead of `strlen()`, but you should not do this. Don't use structs as network protocols.

Answer (score 3):

```
sendto(listener_socket,<This is a char *> , strlen(my_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&nbaddr, sizeof(nbaddr)
```

No it's not, it's a `const void *`. From [a man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html):

```
ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
               const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

Technically you could send your struct with: `&selfRoutingTable` and use `sizeof` for the size, but see below.

---

As EJP mentioned this is a pretty bad idea and you'll quickly run into issues with representations of the struct and its fields on different implementations (and you'll find out all about struct field padding and the like).

Look into a serialization mechanism (json, capnproto, protobufs, xml, asn.1 anything).

---

I now realize that "no it's not" is not always true. Apparently [MSDN lists sendto as taking a `const char *`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740148(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
int sendto(
  _In_       SOCKET                s,
  _In_ const char                  *buf,
  _In_       int                   len,
  _In_       int                   flags,
  _In_       const struct sockaddr *to,
  _In_       int                   tolen
);
```

The idea (of passing the pointer to whatever one wants) stands.